# trouble of making datatable,after initialize <tbody> still empty

Tags: jquery, datatable

i have a problem,,i try to make a table using datatable...i've been download from datatable.net..
but the data grid not show...just the table head (thead)...
where is my fault??

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="datalist">
       <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Line </th>
                 <th>Model </th>
                 <th>Serial </th>
                 <th>NIK </th>
             </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody> </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       var oTable;
       oTable = $("#datalist").dataTable({
             "bRetrieve"  : true,
             "bServerSide": true,
             "bProcessing": true,
             "sAjaxSource": 'showlist.php',
             "aaSorting"  : [[1,"desc"]],
             "aoColumns"  : [
                             /*Line*/  null,
                             /*Model*/ null,
                             /*Serial*/null,
                             /*NIK*/   null
                            ]
             });
       });
</script>
```

at firebug not show error and at post response show result:

```
 {"aaData":[
               ["FA 04","KW-XC555UD","123X0098","12345"],
               ["FA 05","KD-R435UHD","113X0057","12345"],
               ["FA 11","kd-r411uhd","115x0021","12345"],
               ["FA 04","kw-xc406hund","105x1101","12345"],
              ]}
```

Comment: code please!.... you are not new to SO, you know, we can't say, "Oh your fault is there!", when we can't point at anything at all...

Comment: sorry,,i'm late to post my code..

Comment: are you using this one?http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html if yes, please try to check in firebug if `showlist.php` is returning something...

Comment: at firebug not show error and at post response show the result from DB..look at my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've been use this code:

```
$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  // submit SQL to MySQL an$
        $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
        $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

        $sOutput = '{';
        $sOutput .= '"sEcho": '.intval($_POST['sEcho']).', ';
        $sOutput .= '"iTotalRecords": '.$iTotal.', ';
        $sOutput .= '"iTotalDisplayRecords": '.$iFilteredTotal.', ';
        $sOutput .= '"aaData": [ ';
        while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
        {
                $sOutput .= "[";
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Line']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Model']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Serial_number']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['NIK']).'"';
                $sOutput .= "],";
        }
        $sOutput = substr_replace( $sOutput, "", -1 );
        $sOutput .= '] }';

        echo $sOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

I look at the xhr returned value ([of the sample](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html)) and it turned out has a pattern like this,

```
{"sEcho": 1, "iTotalRecords": 57, "iTotalDisplayRecords": 57, "aaData": [ ["Gecko", ....
```

try it in yours and let see if it fixes it...

Comment: that JSON is what the sample page returned in their php... your showlist.php must also return something like that... you can see how to do that here http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem and decided it by this way:

1. downloaded new version of datatables-1.7 from this site (http://datatables.net);
   if this wil not help -
2. try to look through your data in table of your database which you trying to use with datatables. Use any utulity for
   manipulating with databases. Pay attention to records if there are any wrong symbols in the ends of data in some cells like symbols of paragraph etc. If any - try to remove them from data. Then it must work. Good luck.

Comment: sometimes after download datatable files become corrupted.i'm using "1.6".after that i redownload that files.and my project can work normally.